# Chrome Recent Update Forcing Saved Email Into A Search Textbox, How to Disable?

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, single-page-application, autofill

A recent update to chrome(i'm assuming) is aggressively forcing emails of users who saved their credentials on login using chrome into a search textbox. This textbox filters a grid, so having their email forced in their yields no results.

I've tried autocomplete="false/off", removing the modal that contains the login from the dom(ng-if). Giving them descriptive names and ids.

I even tried having the search box added to the DOM 5 seconds after page load, it still forces the email into that box, for some users it adds it multiple times.

Sometimes it re-adds it after erasing it.

Answer (score 1):

Experienced the same; just wanted to populate some inputs with values stored in a cookie, but Google Chrome insisted to fill out the inputs with random crap.

See **https://www.chromium.org/developers/design-documents/form-styles-that-chromium-understands**

Try with `autocomplete="new-password"` instead. Works for me, set it on both the `<form>` (if you are using any) and the `<input>` fields.

Comment: Sorry for the latent response. I disabled the search box in production for the time being. I will try your suggestion in the next few days and mark solution correct if it works!